# 'appendChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

So I'm trying to follow a Tutorial to implement a Solar System by using THREE.js but however I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

This is my current code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf8">
        <title> Solar System Project </title>
        <script src = "three.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>


        <script>

            // Standard Variables / To be changed later.
            var scene, camera, render, container;
            var W,H;

            // On load function...
            window.onload = function() {
                container = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(container);

                W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
                H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);

            }

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W/H, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.z = 4300;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //Sun
            var sun, gun_geom, sun_mat;

            sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(430, 30,30);
            sun_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom,sun_mat);
            scene.add(sun);


            // Earth
            var earth, earth_geom, earth_mat;

            earth_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 20,20);
            earth_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            earth = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom,earth_mat);
            earth.position.x = 2000;
            scene.add(earth);

            render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            render.setSize(W,H);
            container.appendChild(render.domElement);

            var t = 0;

            animate();


            function animate(){
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                sun.rotation.y+=0.001;
                earth.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.1) * 2000;
                earth.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.1) * 1700;

                t+= Math.PI/180*2;

                reneder.render(scene, camera);
            }

        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

The error is occurring at line 49.

I've tried moving it into my on load function but that just creates even more errors.

Thank you.

Comment: You are calling `container.appendChild()` outside of your `onload` callback `container` hasnt been set yet. If you get errors it is probably because you didnt move the scene setup code with it

Comment: Basic indenting of your code would show you your problem....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had two minor issues:

- for simplicity everything should probably go within `onload` you were trying to `appendChild` to the container before the `onload` function had run.
- you had mispelled `render` in your `animate` function

This example has both fixes:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset ="utf8">
    <title> Solar System Project </title>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    
    <script>
      
      // Standard Variables / To be changed later.
      var scene, camera, render, container;
      var W,H;
      
      // On load function...
      window.onload = function() {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        
        W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
        H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
        
        
        
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W/H, 1, 10000);
        camera.position.z = 4300;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        
        //Sun
        var sun, gun_geom, sun_mat;
        sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(430, 30,30);
        sun_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom,sun_mat);
        scene.add(sun);
        
        
        // Earth
        var earth, earth_geom, earth_mat;
        earth_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 20,20);
        earth_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        earth = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom,earth_mat);
        earth.position.x = 2000;
        scene.add(earth);
        
        render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        render.setSize(W,H);
        container.appendChild(render.domElement);
        var t = 0;
        animate();
        
        function animate(){
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          
          sun.rotation.y+=0.001;
          earth.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.1) * 2000;
          earth.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.1) * 1700;
          
          t+= Math.PI/180*2;
          
          // `render` now spelled correctly
          render.render(scene, camera);
        }
        
        // everything now within `onload`
      }
        
        
    </script>
    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Even though VSC didn't catch that misspelled word how did you find it? 0_0

Comment: I just used chrome dev tools - after fixing the `onload` I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: reneder is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

There is zero reason to use `window.onload`. That is left over from 10-15 years ago. You'll notice [not a single example on the three.js site](https://threejs.org/examples) site uses window.onload and neither does any of the examples on [threejsfundamentals.org](https://threejsfundamentals.org).

It's hard to get people to stop using outdated web stuff because there's so many examples of doing it the old way. I haven't used `onload` in probably 10 years at this point. You won't see it in any modern tutorials.

The important part is that any HTML your script accesses appears before it is accessed.

Removing the onload lines (or commenting them out) it just works (except for the one misspelling of `render` as `reneder`.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf8">
        <title> Solar System Project </title>
        <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>


        <script>

            // Standard Variables / To be changed later.
            var scene, camera, render, container;
            var W,H;

            // On load function...
        //    window.onload = function() {
                container = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(container);

                W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
                H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);

        //    }

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W/H, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.z = 4300;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //Sun
            var sun, gun_geom, sun_mat;

            sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(430, 30,30);
            sun_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom,sun_mat);
            scene.add(sun);


            // Earth
            var earth, earth_geom, earth_mat;

            earth_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 20,20);
            earth_mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            earth = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom,earth_mat);
            earth.position.x = 2000;
            scene.add(earth);

            render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            render.setSize(W,H);
            container.appendChild(render.domElement);

            var t = 0;

            animate();


            function animate(){
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                sun.rotation.y+=0.001;
                earth.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.1) * 2000;
                earth.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.1) * 1700;

                t+= Math.PI/180*2;

                render.render(scene, camera);
            }

        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha, thank you for the advice. Just realized that the tutorial I was following was a bit out-dated. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {

    W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
    H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);

    }

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W/H, 1, 10000);
```

Get your container load out of the on load function.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! @LifeOfJona